# Excel Formula INDEX+AGREGATE+ORDER by another column

Tags: excel, formula

I have an excel formula that I need help with, since I'm not that savvy on excel.

The formula is the following:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Liste!$C$2:$N$10000,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Liste!$A$2:$A$10000)-ROW(Liste!$A$2)+1)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BOX"," " & Liste!$B$2:$B$10000 & " ")),ROWS($A$4:$A4)),COLUMN()-1),"")
```

This formula looks on another sheet (*Liste*) for lines containing the word **BOX** on column **B** and show them on "ROWS($D$4:$D4)" (in this case) starting from Column "C".

I'm not even sure if that formula orders the results on column "B" since they're all the same with the word "BOX".

It works prefectly, the only think I can't achieve (and I've tried diferent combinations) is to change that code to make it **show the results in order according to column "C"** (not column B).

Sample Data:

Sheet "Liste"

```
|-----------|----------|-----------|
|     B     |     C    |    D      | 
|-----------|----------|-----------|
|  NOTBOX   |     5    |   SAMPLE  | 
|    BOX    |     3    |   SAMPLE  | 
|    BOX    |     1    |   SAMPLE  | 
|    BOX    |     2    |   SAMPLE  | 
|  NOTBOX   |     4    |   SAMPLE  | 
|-----------|----------|-----------|
```

Current Result:

```
|-----------|----------|
|     A     |     B    |
|-----------|----------|
|     3     |  SAMPLE  |
|     1     |  SAMPLE  | 
|     2     |  SAMPLE  | 
|-----------|----------|
```

Desired Result:

```
|-----------|----------|
|     A     |     B    |
|-----------|----------|
|     1     |  SAMPLE  |
|     2     |  SAMPLE  | 
|     3     |  SAMPLE  | 
|-----------|----------|
```

Can someone give me a hand?

**One thing I forgot to state is that I need to drag this formula around (rows and columns) so it's important that I can drag it on a large zone (if lines are added in the future) and that it ignores the errors (blank).**

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please translate the formula to English. Also, it's helpfull to throw down some sample data with expected output to show us what it is you are trying to achieve =)

Comment: To add to @JvdV comment, [this might come in helpful.](https://excel-translator.de/)

Comment: I'm so sorry, I completely forgot, I should have know better since I hate having to input the formulas on a different language all the time

Comment: I am checking and it is not an easy formula. Two things you should reconsider: `-ROW(Liste!$A$2)+1` is equal to `+1` so place it. On Search, you are not returning values on a vector, so you are getting "BOX" or "NOT BOX", so I don´t know, even, how it is working. With this 2 changes it works.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego, it's actually a prety straightforward formula if we use `SMALL` =)

Comment: @JvdV, in fact, he is ussing `SMALL` on `AGGREGATE(15,6, ...`, what I was not getting is why he ins introducing additional elements on the vector, why he was introducing fixed values as variables... His way can work, but as you expose, can be more simple with an auxiliar column.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego, right. Gotcha =)

Comment: If I use a simple formula like jvjd suggested on the bottom post it does work, but there's still 2 things it doesn't do: 1) Ignoring the errors if you drag more than 3 rows. 2) Being able to drag to the side (columns) aswell (is just repeats the same values). (I don't want to have to put a formula for each column). Thank you for your help so far

Comment: There is just two formulas, and I suggested that you include an iferror to ignore the errors. And also, the second formula you should definitely prefer over a formula you can drag to the right otherwise the performance of your workbook goes down drastically. Arrayformulas are slow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how you could do this:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$6=$E$2,$B$2:$B$6,""),ROW(A1))
```

Or in French

```
=PETITE.VALEUR(SI($A$2:$A$6=$E$2;$B$2:$B$6;"");LIGNE(A1))
```

Formula in `G2`:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$6,MATCH(F2,$B$2:$B$6,0))
```

Or in French

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$6;EQUIV(F2;$B$2:$B$6;0))
```

---

> ***Note:*** The first formula is an array formula and need to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Drag them both down and include an `IFERROR` if you drag these formula's down and you don't want to see errors once there are no more hits.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Your formulas works just fine, there's just 2 thinks that it doesn't do that I need: 1) Ignoring the errors if you drag more than 3 rows. 2) Being able to drag to the side (columns) aswell (is just repeats the same values). (I don't want to have to put a formula for each column). Thank you